# Calling QApplication::exec() after QDialog::exec()

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

in the Qt book, there is an example like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{    
    QApplication app(argc,argv);  
    QDialog dialog;  
    dialog.show();  
    return app.exec();    
}
```

it's well-functioned, but after a little change below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{    
    QApplication app(argc,argv);  
    QDialog dialog;  
    dialog.exec();  
    return app.exec();    
}
```

when I hit the close button on the top-right cornor of the dialog, the dialog window disappered but the program is still running

what's the difference between dialog.exec() and app.exec()?
can I simply use dialog.exec() and then return 0 or what problem will it cause?

Answer (score 4):

The `exec` method of QDialog, QMenu, QCoreApplication runs an event loop. The event loop is infinite.

So the QApplication event loop should be the first one to be started. You should use QDialog::show() or QDialog::open() instead of QDialog::exec() in most cases.

In other words you have the following code:

```
while (1) // QDialog::exec
{
    // Close event  
}

while (1) // QApplication::exec
{
    // There are no events
}
```